# How do I add a Query String in djangos post TestCase?

Tags: django, api, testing, django-rest-framework, query-string

I want to add a querystring in a Django APITestCase of a post function.
This is the Code that I use to test post functions without a query string:

```
self.url_pks = dict(cs_pk=self.cs,
                    kf_pk=self.kf)
url = 'as-list'
self.post_data = dict(model_feature='test')
response = self.post(url, **self.url_pks, data=self.post_data,
                         extra={'format': 'json'})
```

The URL that I would like to test is: /api/cs/7/kf/30/as/?GET=true
So how can I include the '?GET=true'-part?

Answer (score -1):

If you read the docs about [`django.test.Client.post()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post), you will find your answer in the last few paragraphs of that section.

Simply add the params to the url:

```
complete_url = '{}?{}'.format(
    url,
    '&'.join([
        'param1=aa',
        'param2=bb',
    ]))
response = self.post(
    complete_url,
    data=self.post_data,
    extra={'format': 'json'},
    **self.url_pks)
```